# JDBC ResultSet Aggregate Functions

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Edit: oops. These JDBC statements work; I had forgotten to commit in SQL Plus. Thanks Paul.

When I query the database with SQL Plus:

```
select count(tid) from retweets where tid = 35          => 2
select count(tid) from tweets where replyto = 35        => 1
```

I've tried several methods to pull these aggregate counts from the database through JDBC,
but in all cases they returned 0.

Examples:

```
Statement stmt = m_con.createStatement();
ResultSet retweets = stmt.executeQuery("select count(tid) from retweets where tid = 35");

if (retweets.next()) {  System.out.println("# of Retweets: " + retweets.getInt(1));}
 ResultSet replies = stmt.executeQuery("select count(tid) Replies from tweets where replyto = "+tid);


if (replies.next()) {System.out.println("# of Replies : " + replies.getInt("Replies"));}
```

Both times, 0 was printed. Why did this happen and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: No offense, but are you sure there is a record in retweets or tweets that corresponds to 35?

Comment: I've done the first type (with getInt(1)) literally hundreds of times, and it always works.  There has to be something different that you're not telling us, like are you using the same database for the program and for SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
public class TweetDao {
    private static final String SELECT_TWEETS = "SELECT COUNT(tid) as TC FROM TWEETS WHERE replyTo =  ? ";
    // inject this - setter or constructor
    private Connection connection;

    public int getTweetCount(int tid) throws SQLException {
        int tweetCount = -1;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_TWEETS);
            ps.setInt(1, tid);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                tweetCount = rs.getInt("TC");
            }
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);
            DatabaseUtils.close(ps);
        }
        return tweetCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = "select count(tid) from retweets where tid = 35";
PreparedStatement stmt = m_con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

Comment: If you're going to use PreparedStatement, you might as well go the whole way and use a bound variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
**try {
            ps = this.connection.prepareStatement(SELECT_TWEETS);
            ps.setInt(1, tid);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.hasNext()) {
                tweetCount = rs.getInt("TC");
            }
        } finally {
            DatabaseUtils.close(rs);`enter code here`**
```

I think here no need of using while loop because we are getting only single result. Please let me know, if I am wrong.